# If X is a random variable with a Poisson distribution, rate parameter $\lambda$ show that...

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, generating-functions

> If X is a random variable with a Poisson distribution, rate parameter
>   $\lambda$ show that $$E(X(X-1)(X-2)...(X-k)) = \lambda^{k+1}$$

I know that for the probability generating function $G(N)$ of a Poisson random variable, $$G''(1)=E(X(X-1))=\lambda^2$$

and I'm guessing that with each proceeding derivative we add $(X-2), (X-3)$, etc inside the expectation, eg: $G'''(1)=E(X(X-1)(X-2))=\lambda^3$.

But I don't really know how to show it.

Comment: Hint: How does one **define** $G_N(s)$, already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the generating function be $G_X(t)$
$$G_X(t)=e^{\lambda t-\lambda}$$
$$G_X'(t)=\lambda e^{\lambda t-\lambda}$$
$$G_X''(t)=\lambda ^2e^{\lambda t-\lambda}$$
$$G_X^{(n)}(t)=\lambda ^ne^{\lambda t-\lambda}$$

We know that $G_X(1)=E(X)$, and that $G_X^{(n+1)}(1)=E(X(X-1)(X-2)(X-3)...(X-n)$

This is because a PGF is by definition the following:

$$G_X(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P_k t^k$$
Differentiating this gives the following wrt $t$
$$G_X'(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty kP_k t^{k-1}$$
You can see that as we continue to differentiate, we end up with
$$G_X^{(n)}(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)(k-2)...(k-n+1)P_k t^{k-n}$$

This of course is another way of writing the Expected values of $k(k-1)(k-2)...(k-n+1)$ when $t=1$, because the probability of achieving $k$ multiplied by the values is the definition of expected value.

Therefore, it follows that $$G_X^{(n+1)}(1)=E(X(X-1)(X-2)...(X-n))=\lambda ^{n+1}e^{\lambda -\lambda}=\lambda ^{n+1}$$

Comment: I just want to make sure, so shouldn't the alternate way of writing it be  $G_X^{(n)}(1)=E(k(k-1)(k-2)...(k-n-1))$, instead?

Comment: Firstly, Remember that the expected values are $E(X)...$ as opposed to $E(k)...$, also, this formula you just gave does not satisfy what we know the values of $G_X'(1)$ to be.  For example, when $n=1$, this formula gives $E((X)(X-1)(X-2))$ which is not true.  The formula should be $G_X^{(n)}=E(X(X-1)...(X-n+1))$

Comment: Ah, I see. I was having a brain-fart and ignored the negative sign in front of the n. Thank you!